# Radix 128 integer representation of a string

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, hash-function

I am reading a textbook "Introduction to Algorithms" (Cormen, 3rd edition). In the text, the string 'pt' is converted to ASCII such that $p=112$ and $t=116$. The result is then converted to a radix-128 integer by using the following conversion $112\times128 + 116 = 14452 $.

It looks like the conversion proceeds as follows; multiply the first ASCII equivalent ($p=112$ in this case) by the base, $128$, and then add the additional ASCII equivalents. Can I use this conversion scheme for ***any*** string regardless of length? For example, lets say I want to convert the string 'pto' to a radix-128 integer. Since $o=111$ in ASCII, is the corresponding radix-128 integer simply $ 112\times128 + 116 + 111 = 14563 $?

I have done some google searches to find clarification; however, I am not having much luck. I don't think I am asking google the right questions. I would greatly appreciate insight as to why this conversion works (assuming it does).  Basically, the notion of what we are doing here is escaping me. I would greatly appreciate a response that teaches me to fish rather than just gives me a fish.

Comment: $128^2*112+128^1*116+128^0*111 = 1849967$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the standard way of expressing a number in any base (radix).  In base $10$, we have $123=1\cdot 10^2+2 \cdot 10+3\cdot 10^0$.  In base $b$ we have $123_b=1\cdot b^2 +2 \cdot b +3 \cdot b^0$.  You use as many digits as necessary, increasing the power of the base by $1$ for each digit.  You need the base to be (at least) the number of different symbols you are using if you want to represent a string unambiguously.

Comment: So then in the case of 'pto' I gave, it should be $112(128)^2 + 116(128)^1 + 111(128)^0$ and not what I initially listed?

Comment: That is right...

Comment: @RossMillikan. Thank you very much. So $b$ has to be at least as many as symbols we have in the alphabet (e.g. b = 26 for English, b=26 for German, etc.) please? If yes, what is the justification of that please?

Comment: @Avra:  just like base $10$.  We have $10$ digits.  More accurately, you need exactly $b$ symbols in your alphabet.  If there are fewer there are numbers you can't represent.  If there are more some numbers have more than one representation.  Say I work in base $10$ but use the alphabet from hex:  $0-9,A-F$.  I can represent $13_{10}$ as either $13$ or $D$.

Comment: @RossMillikan. Thank you. Is this covered in Radix numbers in number theory? I still want to see proofs that justify why we have to make sure the base is exactly equal to alphabet size. Can you give me a source for a proof please?

Comment: Just count the numbers with a given  number of digits.  If you have $a$ characters in your alphabet there are $a^2$ two letter strings.  This better match $b^2$ or you have trouble.  In base $10$ if I just use characters $0-8$ I can't represent $91$ at all.  Any two digit number is too small and $100$ is too large.  My last comment showed the problem if $a \gt b$